# CSS positioning in different sections

Tags: html, css

I am trying to position two plus signs in two different sections. One plus sign is green, another is black. Green plus sign should show up at the home page (at bottom-center position; 10px up from bottom) and black plus sign should show up at the About page (at bottom-center position as well; also 10px up from bottom).

But both plus signs show at the bottom of Home page and they "cover each other".

They are meant to be links to scroll down to the following page with jquery ( I know how to do this part) but I cannot make them show in different sections.

Why do both signs show in the same section?

Here is JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5QDVs/42/

```
<section id="home">
        <div class="inner">
            <div class="copy">
                <h1 class="logoimage"></h1>
                <div id="button" class="center">
                    <a class="abouttriangle" href="#"></a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>

<section id="about">
    <div class="inner">
        <div class="copy">
            <h1>About</h1>
            <p>Lorem Ipsum bla bla bla...</p>
            <div id="button2" class="center">
                <a class="servicestriangle" href="#"></a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need the sections to be `position: reliative`.
You also have the class `.aboutriangle` and then reference `.abouttriangle`

http://jsfiddle.net/5QDVs/44/

Answer (score 1):

Here you go: http://jsfiddle.net/W5q76/

Since you set the `Position: absolute` on the center class, It's containing parent div must have a `position: relavtive`.

```
    .copy{
      display: inline-block;
      position: relative;
      vertical-align: middle;
      max-width: 85%;
      height:100%;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your CSS class `.center` contains `position: absolute` and is applied to both icons, causing the elements to be positioned in the same location on the page.

Answer (score 0):

## [Live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/aFFWj/)

1. In your jsFiddle, you wrote `aboutriangle` instead of `abouttriangle` in your CSS.
2. You need to set `position:relative;` to `#home` and `#about` because you use absolute positioning in your `.center` class, that will positioned relative to its first positioned
   (not static) ancestor element.
3. Don't forget to add `position:relative;` to every other section if you gonna create more icons that should navigate to the next page.